# Get MySQL data using express ejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

i want to get data from MySQL in to my express ejs.
currently i getting data from this way.

```
    connection.query( 'SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_id = 294', function(err, homeAdjust) {
                var homeAdjust = JSON.stringify(homeAdjust);
return res.render('index', {homeAdjust : homeAdjust});
```

and then get this in to my ejs file like below:

```
<% JSON.parse( homeAdjust ).forEach(function(items){ %>
  <h3><%= items.meta_value %></h3>
 <% }); %>
```

but is there any way to get data form MySQL white single query like this:

```
connection.query( 'SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta', function(err, testimonials) {
  var testimonials = JSON.stringify(testimonials);
  return res.render('index', {testimonials : testimonials});
```

and then i use in ejs file with '.' separation or any other , some thing like this

```
<% JSON.parse(testimonials).meta_key.author_description.forEach(function(item){ %> 

<% }); %>
```

if any help that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you're tying to do, but `testimonials` should be returned as an array, with objects inside:

So

```
connection.query( 'SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta', function(err, testimonials) {
  return res.render('index', {data : testimonials});

<% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>

   <li><% data[i].testimonial %></li>

<% } %>
```

Comment: this is not working...
What i mean is...

I want to display MySQL data in express ejs...using SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta...

In 'postmeta' WHERE meta_key = author_descreption i want  to get value of meta_value of about query.